# unexpected URL returned by express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Here is my following very simple code

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use("/user", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(`<h1>Route is : ${req.url}</h1>`);
});
app.use("/", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(`<h1>Route is : ${req.url}</h1>`);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

what I am expecting is that when I go https:localhost:3000/user ,I want those the URL to be /user but I am getting just / which is unexpected, and even more when I try to go the URL localhost:3000/users, it is handling it by sending the route as /users, I can see that **users** follows the pattern of **user**, so it got matched and handled, however why did the /user route not working?

Comment: In express documentation there is a line - *req.url is not a native Express property, it is inherited from Node’s http module.*

Answer (score 2):

Try **req.originalUrl**,then you will get the correct url.

If i try your code, the url /users is executed in "/" handler, not "/user".

[image: debug of your code with /users url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/988q0.png)